# Can a creature with hexproof be targeted in a graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am constructing a commander deck with [Meren of Clan Nel Toth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Meren%20of%20Clan%20Nel%20Toth).   Can it target creature in graveyard that has hexproof or shroud to return to hand/battlefield? The specific card in my hand is one I want to put in from pure nostalgia from back when I played more frequently..  ([Blastoderm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blastoderm))

Comment: When you have a question about a keyword ability, start by reading what the keyword ability does.

Answer (score 16):

**Hexproof and Shroud cause no problems for targeting creature cards in graveyards.**

Hexproof and Shroud only have an effect on permanents on the battlefield. In other zones they do nothing. This is specified in these rules for [Hexproof](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Hexproof) and [Shroud](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Shroud):

> **702.11b** “Hexproof” **on a permanent** means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”
>
> **702.18a** Shroud is a static ability. “Shroud” means “**This permanent** or player can’t be the target of spells or abilities.”

In addition, Hexproof wouldn't be a problem anyway because Meren only targets cards in your own graveyard, and Hexproof doesn't stop you from targeting things you control.

Comment: > 'Hexproof and Shroud only have an effect on permanents on the battlefield'

The important distinction being "permanent card" vs "permanent". Creatures and other permanents only exist on the battlefield. If any card text mentions "target creature" or "target permanent", you know with certainty they are talking about the battlefield, not any other zone.

Comment: Note that there are cards that give the equivalent shroud to cards in graveyards, such as [Ground Seal](https://scryfall.com/card/c18/149/ground-seal) or [Silent Gravestone](https://scryfall.com/card/rix/182/silent-gravestone)

Comment: I wouldn't say that those give an equivalent to shroud to cards in graveyards because they don't give abilities to cards in graveyards at all. They instead create a rule-modifying effect that changes targeting legality related to cards in graveyards.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, a card text that makes sense while the card is on the battlefield, and doesn't explicitly mention working in any other zone, _only_ works on the battlefield. Of course, when if in doubt, one should check. And when working with a keyword without reminder text, this rule of thumb is of less help.